# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes during shut down

Tags: 16.04, shutdown

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit PC (AMD64) desktop image on my laptop. I updated using `apt-get`. After the successful update, shutdown freezes on the Ubuntu splash screen. How can I fix this?

Comment: It could happen when some process are not willing to be killed during shutdown. Does it happen again ? at next shutdown ? every time ?

Comment: The problem persists everytime I shutdown or any CLI equivalent of shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

It's got something to do with the kernel and systemd. Penguins in linux mint and arch clan are also facing this problem. Just upgrade your kernel to version 4.5 to get rid of it. [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/03/upgrade-linux-kernel-4-5-ubuntu/) is a step by step guide
for the same.